# using arraylist that pass to jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

hi i have a web method that bring data of database and pass it to a jquery ajax function but  i dont know its possible to pass arraylist to jquery and jquery able to recognize it or no and if answer is ok  **how i can use of array list in jquery ajax** .
its my code behind

```
  [WebMethod]
    public ArrayList bringdata()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.;database=site;integrated security=true;");
        int cnt;
        string sSQL = "Select username ,average,weight,point , Rank() over(order by point desc) as 'ranking' from karbar order by point desc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con);

        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds);
        ArrayList arrlst = new ArrayList();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            arrlst.Add(row);
        }
        return arrlst;


    }
```

please help me in jquery code for using arraylist.
thank a lot

Comment: I don't know C# and asp.net, but I guess you can output the ArrayList as JSON and parse it on the client

Comment: you are right but any solution exist for using arraylist in jquery???

Comment: You have Arrays in JavaScript, or `Object`s that might be the representative to C# ArrayLists

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Getdata() {
    PageMethods.bringdata(OnSuccess);
}
function OnSuccess(response) {       
    for (var i in response) {
        alert(response[i]);
    }
} 
</script>
```

instead of the alert you will write your code to append data on the page as per your need.